# programmatically determine generic type

Tags: java, generics

apologies if this is a duplicate.

Is there any way to determine what generic type a class is?

ie I want to know what `T` is....

```
public void doSomething(SomeClass<T> thing)
{
    Class<T> t = ???;
}
```

thanks, p.

Comment: At runtime? Nope -> lookup class erasue, on compiletime be more concrete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in Java.  You will have to accept a parameter of `Class<T>` too, which the caller will have to supply.  (You can do this in the constructor if you would like, so that the class reference will be available to all class methods.)  This is a commonly used hack to determine what `T` refers to at runtime, which is not available otherwise due to the way Java implements generics.